# Google Cloud Run inaccessible even on successful build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My Google Cloud Run image was build successfully using Cloud Build via Github repo. I don't see anything concerning in the build logs.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 10 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:17-slim

RUN set -ex; \
  apt-get -y update; \
  apt-get -y install ghostscript; \
  apt-get -y install pngquant; \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies.
# If you add a package-lock.json speed your build by switching to 'npm ci'.
RUN npm ci --only=production
# RUN npm install --production


# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But when I try to access the cloud through the public URL I see:

```
Oops, something went wrong…
Continuous deployment has been set up, but your repository has failed to build and deploy.
This revision is a placeholder until your code successfully builds and deploys to the Cloud Run service myapi in asia-east1 of the GCP project myproject.

What's next?
From the Cloud Run service page, click "Build History".
Examine your build logs to understand why it failed.
Fix the issue in your code or Dockerfile (if any).
Commit and push the change to your repository.
```

It appears that the node app did not run. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that `cloudbuild.yaml` is not really optional. Adding the file with the following resolved the issue:

```
steps:
    # Build the container image
    - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
      args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/myapi:$COMMIT_SHA", "."]
    # Push the container image to Container Registry
    - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
      args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/myapi:$COMMIT_SHA"]
    # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
    - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
      entrypoint: gcloud
      args:
          - "run"
          - "deploy"
          - "myapi"
          - "--image"
          - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/myapi:$COMMIT_SHA"
          - "--region"
          - "asia-east1"
images:
    - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/myapi:$COMMIT_SHA"
```

Comment: The best answer depends on information missing from your question. Your question does not provide details on how you have configured everything for build and deployment. Your answer is one solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question helped me resolve the issue even though the answer is not super clear. So I will try to expand and provide context for future readers:

The accepted solution is a reference to [this](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#building_and_deploying_a_container) from the docs which in fact is not optional as you would have expected. Specifically, if you want to automate your continuous deployment, you will need to add the `cloudbuild.yaml` to your root directory as follows:

```
  steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA']
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
    - 'run'
    - 'deploy'
    - 'SERVICE-NAME'
    - '--image'
    - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    - '--region'
    - 'REGION'
  images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
```

In addition, you would need to replace `SERVICE-NAME` and `REGION` with the appropriate values for your cloud run service.

Finally, you will need to create a build event trigger in cloud console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers?_ga=2.89539611.1066001161.1698797569-215236956.1696286165&_gac=1.226357480.1696796926.Cj0KCQjwpompBhDZARIsAFD_Fp8D0fMZTskXCoeE-GZ-uEtV54qEoOf31lhBzRZ2M0IpoiIdVR0-_TAaAghEEALw_wcB) where you will need to specify the Cloud Build configuration file you added under Configurations.